# get name of last inserted contact

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am calling and Intent to add contact with startActivityForResult like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT);
                intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
                intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME,
                        u.getName());
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

the problem is that result_code is never **RESULT_OK** (so the **data** in onActivityResult are always null). I think its because when I add a contact a need to press back button to get back to activity.

What I need is to get name of the last inserted contact. What I already tried:

```
        String name = null;
        Cursor cur = appData.getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            cur.moveToFirst(); // or moveToLast
            name = cur.getString(cur
                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

        }
```

Comment: Maybe you could order by `CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP`?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention. Minimal API is 9 :(

Comment: CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP is only available with api level 18 and higher